# InfoPath Designer 2013 - Create a Pop Up Message

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, form, popup

I'm creating a form in InfoPath Designer 2013.  I have it set up with multiple buttons performing different functions (switching views, etc.).  One button I have is a 'Cancel' button.  What this button will do is cancel a Request and send the user back to the SharePoint list.  What I'm hoping to do though is have a pop-up prompt display when the user clicks the 'Cancel' button, a kind of "Are you sure you want to cancel this Request?" prompt.  Is this something I can do in InfoPath Designer 2013?

Thanks?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Habibur Rahaman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/85808/habibur-rahaman) said, popup message in InfoPath is not supported.

Another possible workaround would be use JavaScript to bind the alert function to the button in InfoPath form on the **newifs.aspx** and **editifs.aspx**.

Please see a post with similar request here:
[How to show alert box or popup in infopath 2010 when a button will be clicked.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbe3ec94-7514-406e-874c-6df2688092bb/how-to-show-alert-box-or-popup-in-infopath-2010-when-a-button-will-be-clicked?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, pop up dialog is not supported in the infopath form.** As an alternate, before redirecting to SharePoint URL, in the middle you can create one more view, there you can add this "are you sure?" confirmation message.. then add **ok** and **cancel**, on ok button click redirect to SharePoint URL.